# How to give a background image to two different components in Angular?

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm trying to implement this design:

[image: Sonido landing page]

and as you can see, there's a background image that covers both navbar and the content below it. Problem is, in my code, the navbar is a separate component from the content below it and I have no idea how to make this background be the background for both of these components.

this is my `main-layout.component.html` code:

```
<navbar></navbar>
<main>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</main>
```

This is what loads in the router outlet:

```
<hero-content></hero-content>
<general-information></general-information>
<contact-us></contact-us>
<footer></footer>
```

I need the background image to cover behind `<navbar>` and `<hero-content>` components.

Answer (score 0):

create one

```
<div>
    // inside div tag add background image with url based condition
    <navbar></navbar>
    <main>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </main>
</div>
```

Comment: how do I give it based on the url though?

Comment: [ngStyle]="{'background-image': !image? 'url(\'image url')'"}

 image:boolean = true;
 constructor(public _http:Router) { _http.events.subscribe(()=> this.router = this._http.url);
 if(this._http.url  == 'hero') // hero is url
 {
  this.image = false
 }
 }